# How to update certain columns in table to truncate records after certain length and regex replace string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a list of columns in a table that I want to truncate to 255 records max and remove any percent signs from the columns, how would I do this?

```
old Table

col1                                              col2    
adfaadfadfadfdfdafdjf;kldjf;adjsfjads;f            60%

new Table


col1                                              col2    
adfaadfadfadf                                      60
```

col1 is not representative of the full string only used for illustration purposes.

I am using sql server 2012.

code so far:

```
SELECT
case 
    when len(col)=255
    then left(col, 255)
    else col end col
from table
```

Comment: Removing the percent sign is trivial. Look at using REPLACE. But the first part of your question I don't understand. How do you truncate a column to 255 records? That makes no sense. Are you saying you want the first 255 characters in a single column? That would also be trivial, use LEFT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this not as simple as...?

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET StringColumn = LEFT(StringColumn,255),
    PercentColumn = REPLACE(PercentColumn,'%','')
GO

--You then probably want to fix that column's datatype.
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN PercentColumn int; --Assuming integer values only.
```